# Determine the value of h such that the matrix is the augmented matrix of a consistent linear system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Determine the value of h such that the matrix is the augmented matrix of a consistent linear system.
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 && h && 4 \\
> 3 && 6 && 8
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I'm entirely unsure how to go about solving this.

This how far I got:

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
1 && h && 4 \\
0 && (6-3h) && -4
\end{bmatrix} R_2' = R_2-3R_1
$$

$$
6-3h=-4 \\
6+4=3h \\
10=3h \\
h=3/10 \text{ ?}
$$

> New progress

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 6 && 8 \\
1 && h && 4
\end{bmatrix}
R_1 \leftarrow\rightarrow R_2
$$

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 6 && 8 \\
0 && (h-2) && 4/3
\end{bmatrix}
R_2' = - \frac13 R_1
$$

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 6 && 8 \\
0 && 3(h-2) && 4
\end{bmatrix}
R_2' = 3R_2
$$

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 6 && 8 \\ \\
0 && 1 && \frac{4}{3(h-2)}
\end{bmatrix}
R_2' = R_2 \div 3(h-2)
$$

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
-3 && 0 && z \\ \\
0 && 1 && \frac{4}{3(h-2)}
\end{bmatrix}
R_1' = 6R_2 - R_1 \\
z = -8 + \frac{24}{3(h-2)} = \frac{-32(h-2) + 24}{3(h-2)}
$$

$$
\sim\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 0 && z \\ \\
0 && 1 && \frac{4}{3(h-2)}
\end{bmatrix}
R_1' = -\frac13 R_1 \\
z = - \frac{-32(h-2) + 24}{(h-2)}
$$

Comment: Did you try Gaussian Elimination (Row Reduced Echelon Form).

Comment: udated with my work of progress so far. I have tried row operations but it was confusing

Comment: What do you mean by R2/(3(h-2))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these row operations:

- Swap $R_1$ and $R_2$
- $R_2 \rightarrow -R_1/3 + R_2$
- $3R_2$
- Divide $R_2/(3(h-2))$
- $R_1 \rightarrow 6R_2 - R_1$
- Divide $R_1/3$

This should provide the value of $h$ that makes the system inconsistent.

**Spoiler - Do Not Peek**

> $\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && \dfrac{8(h-3)}{3(h-2)} \\ 0 && 1 && \dfrac{4}{3(h-2)}\end{bmatrix}$

Notes:

- Sometimes you can also look at the determinant of the system, in this case it is $6-3h$ (what value of $h$ would make this inconsistent).
- You could have also reduced and solved the system as another approach. You get $y = \dfrac{4}{3(2-h)}$ and can substitute back.
- There are other approaches.

Comment: I shown my work/steps as you said but I had to change the $R_1/3$ to a $R_1/-3$ to make the leading 1 non-negative. Does it look right?

Comment: I had the negative in my answer. Looks like you an algebra error near the end in $z$. You should get exactly what I showed. Regards

Comment: @user1766555: Shouldn't your $32$ be a $24$?

Comment: Nice work, here! +1

Comment: Indeed, I see! Shame on me, I peeked! :X

Comment: I just noticed: for a little while, anyway, we both have the same last three digits in our reputation! Have a great day and a great new week!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the matrix in the first two columns. It is invertible iff $h\not=2$; this is indicated by computing the determinant.